# How to disable Weak Ciphers from Azure mobile service?

Tags: iis, encryption, registry, azure-mobile-services, rc4-cipher

Is there any way to disable weak ciphers from Azure Mobile Service?
The service is running in Standard tier.
Publish server port is 443.

I tried to run following code

```
string[] subKeys = new string[]
{
    "RC4 40/128",
    "RC4 56/128",
    "RC4 64/128",
    "RC4 128/128",
};

RegistryKey parentKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers", true);

foreach (string keyName in subKeys)
{
    var newKey = parentKey.CreateSubKey(keyName);
    newKey.SetValue("Enabled", 0);
    newKey.Close();
}
parentKey.Close();
```

refered from [How to disable RC4 cipher on Azure Web Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777559/how-to-disable-rc4-cipher-on-azure-web-roles)

But getting `Requested registry access is not allowed` exception

It is mentioned in same link to add `executionContext="elevated" in the startup`
I'm not sure where to add this line or how to apply web role to mobile service..

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can control within Azure Mobile Services.  Check out this question on testing which ciphers are allowed: https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers