# How to disable RC4 cipher in Azure VM Scaleset

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, windows-server-2016, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a VM scale set with this image:

```
Publisher: MicrosoftWindowsServer
Offer: WindowsServer
SKU: 2016-Datacenter-with-Containers
Version: latest
```

These machines are running SSL web endpoint hosted in service fabric. The website is build in dotnetcore with a WebListener which propably uses the http.sys

I was wondering why new VM images still supports RC4 ciphers and how to disable them. I don't want to do it manually because that will break to autoscaling.

Similar issue, but then for Worker roles: [How to disable RC4 cipher on Azure Web Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777559/how-to-disable-rc4-cipher-on-azure-web-roles)

Comment: well it doesn't make sense, use a script to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treating this as two separate questions:

1. For the Windows 2016 virtual machine images - typically backwards compatibility is prioritized to avoid breaking existing applications which rely on older protocols. Adding the windows-server-2016 tag in case anyone wants to comment further on that.
2. For scale sets - Write a custom script extension to apply the same changes you'd have applied manually. This will then apply to every VM, and new VMs that are subsequently created.

Comment: I ran this script: https://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12 as a CustomScriptExtension and the RC4 is disabled. Thanks.